# Travis CI not recognizing renamed repository

Tags: heroku, continuous-integration, command-line-interface, travis-ci

So I originally named my github repo `my_repo`, but then renamed it `my-repo` shortly after creation, like within the first day. This was roughly a year ago.

Ever since, I've been building the project with Travis CI, using the free .org version. Now after making all my repos private and upgrading to the pro version with travis-ci.com, I've had to provide new API credentials in my .travis.yml. So I have to do so with

```
travis encrypt $(heroku auth:token) --add deploy.api_key --pro
```

This has worked with other repositories, but not this particular one. Instead, I get

```
repository not known to https://api.travis-ci.com/: dben89x/my_repo
```

However, on my Travis CI dashboard, it's trying to build it as `dben89x/my-repo`. I'm not sure how to tell travis to build it as `dben89x/my-repo`.

All my git remotes are set up as `my-repo`. I've tried logging out in the CLI  and logging back in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/3264#issuecomment-180246348

Went into `.git/config` and changed

```
[travis]
  slug = dben89x/my_repo
```

to

```
[travis]
  slug = dben89x/my-repo
```